# Comparing List<KeyValuePair<>> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm developing a program which needs to hold a list of scores and strings and I believe a `List<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>` would be the best list to use. I can't use a Dictionary as the keys are not unique so I use Insert and BinarySearch to keep the list sorted and I don't want to use List.Sort after each insert as I'm adding many items. ‌In my code I have:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>> list;

List<string> values = new List<string>
{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
};

// Insert values
list.Insert(index, new KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>(score, values));

// Find index of new position
int index = list.BinarySearch(new KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>(score, values), new Comparer());

private class Comparer : IComparer<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>
{
    public int Compare(
        KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> x,
        KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> y)
    {
        if ((x.Key == y.Key) && (x.Value[0] == y.Value[0]))
            return 0;
        if ((x.Key < y.Key) || ((x.Key == y.Key) && (x.Value[0] != y.Value[0])))
            return 1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

'list' is maintained in descending score order and BinarySearch checks that the score and first value isn't already in the list or return its position in the list but I can't get Comparer to work. An example list would be:

`23, Harry, Ottawa, Green
17, Amy, Venice, Red
17, Sue, Sydney, Blue
4, Harry, Durban, Blue`

In this example `4, Harry, Miami, Red` would be invalid as `4, Harry...` already exists. Inserting `9, Dallas...` would return 3 as the new position.

However I get the error `CS0535 'Comparer' does not implement interface member 'IComparer<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>.Compare(KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>, KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>)'` on the class. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: So, you can't insert `4, Harry, Miami, Red` because `Harry` is already in 23, right ?

Comment: You can use a dictionary.  Dictionary<int, List<string>>.

Comment: It's because the pair 4, Harry... is already listed as 4, Harry, Durban, Blue so I couldn't add this new item. The combination of the first two items, e.g. 4, Harry must be unique.

Comment: Are you trying to compare that every value in the List<string> matches?  You are only one value of the list.

Comment: @jdweng Does Dictionary allow duplicate keys, as in two values of 17 in my example list?

Comment: So you have a many to one mapping.  That does not prevent you from using a dictionary.  The keys are still unique just the values can be duplicated.

Comment: When I need to add a new item I need to check the int and first string value pair, e.g. `4, Harry...` doesn't already exist in the list and if not, return the position in the list according to its score so it can be added to the list at position `index`.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the first element of the values has a special meaning.

The combination of the integer value along with that first element being unique, you can use a `Dictionary` having a tuple combining that integer and the first element of the list as key :

[Try the below code yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2ZAWN)

```
// A SortedDictionary is like a Dictionary, but automatically sorted on the key
var dict = new SortedDictionary<(int, string), List<string>>();

var key = (23, "Harry");
// If you are using .NET Core 2.0 or above, you can use
/*
 * if (!dict.TryAdd(key, new List<string> { "Ottawa", "Green" }))
 *     Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");
 */
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, new List<string> { "Ottawa", "Green" });
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");

key = (4, "Harry");
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, new List<string> { "Durban", "Blue" });
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");

key = (4, "Harry");
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, new List<string> { "this is", "duplicate" });
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");

key = (17, "Amy");
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, new List<string> { "Venice", "Red" });
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");

key = (17, "Sue");
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
    dict.Add(key, new List<string> { "Sydney", "Blue" });
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Can't add {key}");

Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Notice now how sorted is the dictionary");
Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
foreach (var Key in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"dict[{Key}] Contains : ");
    foreach (var val in dict[Key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{val}");
    }
}
```

This outputs :

```
Can't add (4, Harry)
---------------------------------------
Notice now how sorted is the dictionary
---------------------------------------
dict[(4, Harry)] Contains : 
    Durban
    Blue
dict[(17, Amy)] Contains : 
    Venice
    Red
dict[(17, Sue)] Contains : 
    Sydney
    Blue
dict[(23, Harry)] Contains : 
    Ottawa
    Green
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and example. I'm using .NET4.8 and your example worked perfectly. How do I list the 5 highest scoring names and locations from the dictionary, e.g. Harry, Ottawa; Sue, Sydney etc.?

Comment: Quick and dirty answer : `foreach (var Key in dict.Keys.Skip(Math.Max(0, dict.Keys.Count() - 5)))` will allow you to take the last 5 entries (or all entries if there is less than 5). The last 5 because the `SortedDictionary` is ascending sorted. You can then display `$"{Key.Item2}, {dict[Key][0]}"`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message the `new Comparer()` in `int index = list.BinarySearch(new KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>(score, values), new Comparer());` does not initialize your `private class Comparer : IComparer<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>>` but the [System.Collections.Comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.comparer?view=netframework-4.8) one.You should add the namespace to it like this: `new YourNamespaceHere.Comparer()`